# Add ngx-mask directive to existing Angular component class

Tags: angular, angular-directive, directive, ngx-mask

Is there a way to add a directive - `ngx-mask` in my case - to an existing Angular component that has a *named* HTML element `input` (`#datePicker` in the example below)?

## Example setup

Suppose I have a component called `InputDate.component.ts` as shown below. The template in the component - the HTML part - calls another component whose selector is `bb-input-datepicker-ui`. This selector's component - `InputDatepicker.component.ts` - has within its template elements such as `label` and `input`, but it's assumed that we do not have its sourcecode immediately available - we can only pass values to it through the `@Input()` fields.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bb-us-formly-input-date',
  template: `<bb-input-datepicker-ui
      [label]="to.label"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [minDate]="to.minDate"
      #datePicker
    ></bb-input-datepicker-ui>
  `,
})
export class InputDateComponent extends FieldType implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('datePicker', { static: true })
  datePickerComponent: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // sample experiment code
    let comp:HTMLElement = this.datePickerComponent.datePickerInput.nativeElement;
    comp.setAttribute('placeholder', '77/99/5555')
    comp.setAttribute('mask', '00/00/0000')
    console.log('==', comp);
  }
}
```

## Wishes

I would like to be able to latch the `ngx-mask` directive on the `InputDatepicker`'s `input` element. Now, if I re-create the `InputDatepicker` component at my end, all I would need to do is add a mask *key=value* pair like this as one of the many attributes of `input`:

```
<input ... mask="00/00/0000" ...>
```

which would guarantee two things: 1) only digits can be typed in, and 2) date is auto-formatted to the mask shown - wonderful.

That said, I would like to use `InputDatepicker` component as-is and should not ideally re-create it at my end. Hence the question: **can I somehow add the mask directive dynamically to it**?

## Already done...

If you see the `ngAfterViewInit()` above, you should see a humble attempt at doing this. The `console.log` would print something like the output below, and would show the `placeholder` attribute being added and the UI does show it. No luck with the `mask` directive however, even though it's shown in the output. It's just not the right way of latching directives on `input` elements dynamically I suppose.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ... placeholder="77/99/5555" mask="00/00/0000">
```

Thanks for your time friends.

Comment: I developed a nice solution I will be posting shortly.